# Trouble with triple join

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

**orders**

```
orderID
userID
```

**users**

```
userID
lastViewedOrderID
```

**votehistory**

```
userID
orderID
```

I have a PHP function: `getOrdersForUser($userID)`, which should return a set of orderID values with the following conditions:

1) the user has not yet viewed the orders (orders.orderID > users.lastViewedOrderID)

2) the orders were not placed by the user being queried (orders.userID != users.userID)

3) has not been voted on by that user according to the votehistory table (orderID is not in votehistory where userID = [userID value passed in])

So far the best I've come up with is:

```
SELECT orders.orderID
FROM orders 
JOIN users 
ON users.userID != orders.userID 
JOIN votehistory
ON (votehistory.userID = users.userID) AND (votehistory.orderID != orders.orderID )
WHERE users.userID = [the userID value passed in] 
AND orders.orderID > users.lastViewedOrderID
AND likehistory.orderID != orders.orderID
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a ton of repeats - the same orderID repeats for each valid row in votehistory. I don't seem to understand how the JOIN process is optimized. Am I supposed to try to reduce the number of rows in the tables being joined through subqueries? What is the most efficient way to exclude the duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a few indexes, I found this query to work efficiently:

```
SELECT orders.orderID
FROM orders
WHERE orders.orderID NOT IN  
( 
    SELECT votehistory.orderID 
    FROM users 
    JOIN votehistory
    ON (votehistory.userID = users.userID) 
    WHERE users.userID = [userID input value]   
)
AND orders.userID != [userID input value]
AND orders.orderID > 
(
    SELECT lastViewedOrderID
    FROM users
    WHERE userID = [userID input value]
)
ORDER BY orders.orderID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you just want orderID you could do it with an `EXISTS`. Like this:

```
SELECT orders.orderID
FROM orders
WHERE EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM users 
    JOIN votehistory
    ON (votehistory.userID = users.userID) 
    WHERE users.userID != orders.userID 
    AND users.userID = [the userID value passed in] 
    AND (votehistory.orderID != orders.orderID )
    AND orders.orderID > users.lastViewedOrderID
    AND likehistory.orderID != orders.orderID
)
```

Reference:

- [13.2.9.6 Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll actually need more than orderID, though - this is just a simplified version of my tables. Would I need the joins in that case?

Comment: @GoldenJoe : It depends on where the additional fields are coming from. Just have in mind that if you do a join in might cause that it returns duplicates again

Comment: What if I wanted to get one field from each of the three tables?

Comment: @GoldenJoe : Then you will have the same problem